# CSVHelper: GetRecords<T> throws Format exception for null dates

Tags: c#, datetime, csvhelper

I am using `GetRecords` function and Entity Framework for the Template class .
There is a nullable dateTime property in the class.

While parsing the csv (which has "null" data for that dateTime column )using `GetRecords`, i am getting Format exception : "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0."

> Stack trace: at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
>   at System.DateTime.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles styles)
>   at CsvHelper.TypeConversion.DateTimeConverter.ConvertFromString(TypeConverterOptions options, String text)
>   at CsvHelper.TypeConversion.NullableConverter.ConvertFromString(TypeConverterOptions options, String text)
>   at lambda_method(Closure )
>   at CsvHelper.CsvReader.CreateRecordT
>   at CsvHelper.CsvReader.d__631.MoveNext() at System.Collections.Generic.List1..ctor(IEnumerable1 collection) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)
>   at HBServiceCodeMapper.Program.ProcessExcel(String filePath, DateTime startDate, DateTime modificationDate) in d:\REPOSITORY\StandAloneApps\trunk\HBServiceCodeMapper

Is there something i am doing wrong? or is it the null data?

Comment: It would be better to show [MCVE] of your problem.

Comment: CSV data: 

SEQUENCE,DESCRIPTION,UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER,SERVICE_CODE,OP_NAME,CREATION_USER,CREATION_DATE,MODIFICATION_DATE
10893,ABACO,T01-E-INTRACEOF,2100403,Abaco colonial villa,AREYNOLDS,6/20/2014 12:59,NULL

when i parse this data.. i get the exception stated above and 


SEQUENCE,DESCRIPTION,UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER,SERVICE_CODE,OP_NAME,CREATION_USER,CREATION_DATE,MODIFICATION_DATE
10893,ABACO,T01-E-INTRACEOF,2100403,Abaco colonial villa,AREYNOLDS,6/20/2014 12:59,

when i parse this.. there is no exception and MODIFICATION_DATE
column has null value

Comment: I have following columns: 
SEQUENCE,DESCRIPTION,UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER,SERVICE_CODE,OP_NAME,CREATION_USER,CREATION_DATE,MODIFICATION_DATE
with data: 
10958,Ephesus & Virgin Mary's House,T01-E-EPHESUSIST,EPHESUSIST,Ephesus and Virgin Mary's house,RECEP,2013-02-07 15:03:31.0,null
For column Modification Date , i am given null value from customer. 
If i try the same data by replacing null with blank , i.e:
10958,Ephesus & Virgin Mary's House,T01-E-EPHESUSIST,EPHESUSIST,Ephesus and Virgin Mary's house,RECEP,2013-02-07 15:03:31.0, 
It parses perfectly fine.